# Scala Spark sort RDD by index of substring

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala Spark and I have a question.

I have RDD that contains 120 million strings, I'm trying to find all string that contains the sub-string. this I'm doing fine.

Now I want to sort the output by the index so that found string that the sub-string is closer to the start will be first.

For example:

The sub-string:  **abcdefg**

The strings:

s1 = tryu**abcdefg**yui

s2 = tr**abcdefg**yui

s3 = **abcdefg**yuo

So my desired output should be a list\rdd that is sorted {s3, s2, s1}

What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to transform the `RDD[String]` to `RDD[(String,Index)]` where the Index is calculated using Java's String `indexOf`.

```
// Dataset
val r = sc.makeRDD(Seq("abf", "ffff", "aaaaaabf", "ttggabf"))

// Sorting on index of substring "bf", only for those strings that contain "bf"
val sorted = r.map(s => (s, s.indexOf("bf"))).filter(_._2>0).sortBy(_._2)
```